# Socket.io, Codeigniter, Redis session store to create push notifications

Tags: node.js, socket.io-1.0

I have a codeigniter app I want to implement push notifications for. I use mysql as backend database, but I use redis as the session store so I can use it with node (just preference). When a user connects to node they pass there session id via the query parameter on

```
io.connect('http://123.45.67.89:3434', { query: "sessId="+sessionId })
```

and on the server I get it like this:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, accept) {

    // get user details from redis using the session id sent here

    console.log('User Session Id: ', handshakeData._query.sessId);
    accept(null, true);
});
```

I am able to get the users data out of redis to save a list of connected users.

I want to save a list of connected users in an array with their profile_id and the socket.id

```
client_list[user.profile_id] = socket.id;
```

so i can search for users via id and get their socket connection id and send that user a notification for what ever reason.

My problem is I can send the sessionId in the authorization event but can't get the socket.id, and I can get the socket.id in the connection event but can't pass data along on that event.

How can I send a session id and get the socket.id on connection to the socket.io server?

Thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can access the data from the query sent in the authorization event in the connection event like:

```
socket.request._query.sessId
```

(sessId is a custom key sent from client connection query, see question for clarification)

This way you can capture the users socket.id and data from the query on the connection event.